# why there is always some null values when I use "insert into" in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I created a table and define the data type of every field which is the same with the source table. When I use "insert into table select ..." to fulfill data in this new table, there is no debug error. And I am sure the 'productid' field has no null value in source table which is bigint type. But after the inserting, I find a little amount of  records' productid is null. I also try stored as textfile and parquet. It makes no sense that there is still null values in outcome table.

However, when I use "creata table as select .... from ...", there is no null in the outcome productid.

So I don't know where is the problem? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This happens mostly when the actual data which you are trying to load have different datatype than destination Hive table column data type in DDL OR if length is smaller in target table. Check `productid` missing value in terms of actual data in it and length Vs defined in DDL statement.